# How can I extract the main price value from this on my mvc view?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

```
?((webEPOS.Models.cPrice)((new System.Collections.Generic.Mscorlib_CollectionDebugView<webEPOS.Models.cProductOption>(this.ProductOptions)).Items[0])).MainPrice
12
```

How can i unwrap this to get actual value at my mvc view for main price?

```
this.ProductOptions[0]
{MAFIA webEPOS.Models.cProductSize}
    base {webEPOS.Models.cPrice}: {MAFIA webEPOS.Models.cProductSize}
    IsDeleted: false
    OptionID: 12
    ParentName: "MAFIA"
    Position: 0
    ProductID: 7
    SizeDescription: "7''"
    SizeID: 1
    SizeInfo: {webEPOS.Models.cProductSize}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm making lots of assumptions here as your question needs more detail, but it looks like cPrice is your base class with a property of MainPrice?

So if your View declaration is

```
@model List<cProductOption>
```

And you've passed the product options from your ActionResult like so:

```
return View(this.ProductOptions);
```

I'm guessing that the Items collection is loosely typed because of the way you've written that code above. You don't want to be phlucking about with that kind of code in the view; do it safely server side by writing an extension method on cProductOption that will grab it gracefully:

```
public static decimal MainPrice (this cProductOption cproductOption) {

    decimal returnValue = 0m;

    try {
        // returnValue = try and get it from .Items[0], casting to the type you need and/or seeing if the necessary relationships exist.
    }
    catch(Exception exception){
        // log the possible exception
    }

    return returnValue;
}
```

Then because you have your inheritance sorted out the way you do you can simply iterate through the Model list:

```
@foreach (cProductOption cproductOption in Model) {
    @cProductOption.MainPrice()
}
```

Like I said, I'm making educated guess at some of this, but hopefully it gives you some pointers. Good luck with your app!